# C# hashSet of Lists

Tags: c#

I'm quite new to C# and I have a question regarding HashSets. I have used them to get unique values from lists, but now I'm trying to use them with nested lists. I have a List of Lists(each containing 2 numbers) and I want to pull out unique pairs of numbers

For example, I have some panels. For each one, I have put their dimensions(lenght width) into a list and put that list into another list, so I have something like this:
[  [10,5], [10,6], [10,5],[10,7], [10,7] ]
What I want would be to extract unique pairs of information so that I would have:
[ [10,5], [10,6], [10,7] ]

How would I go about this

Answer (score 1):

You can let another class do it for you or handle it using lambda expression and convert your List to HashSet...
and how :)...
For first approach there is an interface in .net called IEqualityComparer.
You can implement this interface in a custom class like this:

```
class ListEqCompare : IEqualityComparer<List<int>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<int> x, List<int> y)
    {
        if (x.Count != y.Count)
            return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Count; i++)
        {
            if (x[i] != y[i])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<int> obj)
    {
        int hash = 0;
        foreach (int num in obj)
            hash = hash ^ EqualityComparer<int>.Default.GetHashCode(num);

        return hash;
    }
}
```

In this class the hash of each list is computed using XOR of hash of all numbers in the list... you can use other approaches such as Add, Multiplication and etc. depending on the domain of your problem.
Once the hash is ready and two objects have the same hash the Equals() function plays the role and compares the lists...
at the end you can use your class in this way:

```
var newList = list.Distinct(new ListEqCompare());
```

Another way is to convert the Lists to HashSets and compare them using the existing function of HashSets...

```
var newList = list.Select(x => new HashSet<int>(x))
               .Distinct(HashSet<int>.CreateSetComparer()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a list of `Tuple<T1, T2>` objects rather than a list of lists.  Advantages to using `Tuple`s are that it ensures all of the elements inside the list contain the same number of subelements, and it prevents them from being modified after they are created.

Answer (score 0):

First, since you're storing only 2 values in child lists, you can use [KeyValuePair structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx) for storing data. Then you can do this:

```
            var initialList = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
            var listOfDistinctItems = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
            //populate initial list ...

            foreach(var item in initialList)
            {
                if (listOfDistinctItems.Exists(di => di.Key == item.Key && di.Value == item.Value))
                    continue;

                listOfDistinctItems.Add(item);
            }
```